# Section counter punctuation in an AMS article is positioned in LTR direction instead of RTL

Tags: sectioning, lyx, amsart, right-to-left, lyx-layouts

I'm using `amsart` with XeTeX, LyX, and writing an article in an RTL language. Enumerations within text should normally position their punctuation in the opposite direction to separate between their contents and their counting.

In my case, the **period** is positioned to the right of the number, but it should be to the left of the number (because the text continues on the left, not on the right). The counter itself as a whole is positioned correctly (on the right), but not the period. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

In the screenshot, the bold text that reads "**.תת־כותרת**" is a subsection, and its counter has positioned the period correctly.

Above is a section that reads "כותרת", with the period positioned incorrectly to the right of "2" (as if the line starts with a period).

I searched for similar cases where people wrote RTL in `amsart` and dealt with it, but I found none. Is there any way I could fix that? Or should I stop trying RTL in `amsart` altogether?

---

LyX's own definitions of layouts in its installation directory (on Debian) at `/usr/share/lyx/layouts/` such as: `amsart.layout`, `stdsections.inc`, `stdlists.inc`, `stdcounters.inc` don't affect this, because LyX is using them mostly within the editor itself for display. When the document is compiled, the sections and subsections are defined by `amsart.sty`.

The `.lyx` file of your document doesn't affect this problem either, because it only references back to LyX's own layouts, and not `amsart`'s command.

The generated TeX code from LyX's *Code Preview Pane* is the only useful information I found, as it pointed to the `\section` and `\subsection` commands I should lookup at `amsart.sty`.

---

The problem is within 'amsart.sty', and not with LyX's layout or generated TeX files. I briefly searched the [code documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsclass.pdf) (PDF) of `amsclass` that I found at [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsart?lang=en), and the counters used by sections are being defined at line 1158 onwards. See in the answer what was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine the AMS sections to be numbered in RTL by pasting this to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\RL{\arabic{section}}}
```

[image: Image showing the problem fixed]

The main difference between this and `amsart`'s definition of sections is the `\RL` command.

The strange part is that using `\LR` instead of `\RL` also fixes the problem.

If you encounter similar issues with subsections and subsubsections, you probably want to try renew those commands as well with `\RL` or `\LR`.

**Alternatively**, if your language is RTL and you want to use its alphabet as numerals, then you may renew the command as follows even without `\RL`.

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\alph{section}}
```

[image]